# Array vs long vectors in Verilog

Tags: arrays, vector, verilog, fpga

I am writing a Verilog code that needs to hold many data in a memory-like structure.

I have implemented them using both an array of vectors and a really long single vector.

Although I don't think there is any difference internally, which, if there is, is a better way of storing data?

I'm actually writing a code that will synthesize onto a board, so any practical advice from those who've had a lot of experience with FPGA will help.

For example, I could store 32x1024 data using

```
reg[31:0] temp_storage [0:1023]
```

or

```
reg[32767:0] temp_storage
```

The array method is much easier for the programmer to manage, but is there any disadvtange from the perspective of the hardware?

Would it actually be the same if I declared everything one by one?

```
reg[31:0] temp_storage0001
reg[31:0] temp_stoarge0002
.
.
.
reg[31:0] temp_storage1024
```

Thank you.

Comment: look for memory inference templates in your synthesizer docs. With independent registers you should be able to access them all in the same cycle, so it won't create a memory. With the array you may get one, maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big difference between these two formats.

Format one:

```
reg[31:0] temp_storage [0:1023];
```

This is can be mapped<sup>*</sup> on a memory block and as such will use significant less FPGA registers/recources. But there is penalty: you can read or write maximum two entries at a time.
(Two entries if you use dual ported memory, one if you use single ported memory. All embedded block rams in FPGAs are dual ported these days)

Format two:

```
reg[31:0] temp_storage0001
reg[31:0] temp_stoarge0002
```

In this case every `temp_storage...` is stored in a separate set of 32 registers. You can access as many as you like simultaneous reading and writing (or as much until you run out of FPGA gates). Thus the flexibility is much larger but this will use up you FPGA gates/LUTS much faster.

<sup>*</sup> <sub>As @B.Go says: check your FPGA documentation how exactly you get this mapped onto memory, or infer memory macro/IP directly.</sub>

---

> What do you exactly mean by maximum of two entries: temp_storage[0] <= t_data; temp_storage[1] <= t_data.

```
reg[31:0] temp_storage [0:1023];
```

The above definition is for a memory which has 1024 entries each 32 bits wide. You can select two entries of the 1024 and you can read or you can write each entry. (Your dual-ported memory normally has two address buses, two read data ports and two write data ports and often also two clocks, on per port).

You would normally access this memory using something like:

```
always @( posedge clk)
begin
   if (write_enable_0)
      temp_storage[address_0] <= write_data_0;
   else
      read_data_0 <= temp_storage[address_0];

   if (write_enable_1)
      temp_storage[address_1] <= write_data_1;
   else
      read_data_1 <= temp_storage[address_1];
end
```

Find the 'memory' section /application note of your FPGA family which will tell you how to do thus and also the pitfalls (e.g. writing and reading at the same time from the same location)

Comment: What do you exactly mean by maximum  of two entries:
temp_storage[0] <= t_data;
temp_storage[1] <= t_data;
temp_storage[2] <= t_data;
is not possible in one clock cycle?